# How to drop a file into a QTableWidget in PyQt5

Tags: python, file, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to create a table-widget where I can drop an audio file and populate the table with filename, size of file etc. My code is as follows. I haven't implemented  the part for reading the metadata on dragEnterEvent as the table isn't even accepting drops of any kind.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(982, 615)
        MainWindow.setAcceptDrops(True)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 0, 271, 181))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 701, 331))
        self.tableWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tableWidget.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.tableWidget.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.tableWidget.setShowGrid(False)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 982, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.titleUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def titleUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("tableWidget")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I get the table to accept drops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you should import the file created by `pyuic` rather than editing it directly, otherwise all your edits will be lost if you make further changes in Qt Designer. (The example code below will show how to do that).

Secondly, you need to ensure that the table accepts drops and that it specifies the kinds of data it can receive. With that in place, you can then listen for drop events and add any dropped files to the table.

Before using the example below, you should re-run `pyuic`. The example assumes the ui module will saved as *mainwindow.py* in the same directory. If you want to use a different name, you will need to edit the import line accordingly.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('TableWidget')
        self.tableWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.tableWidget.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        types = ['text/uri-list']
        types.extend(self.tableWidget.mimeTypes())
        self.tableWidget.mimeTypes = lambda: types
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Drop and
            event.mimeData().hasUrls()):
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                self.addFile(url.toLocalFile())
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def addFile(self, filepath):
        row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(filepath)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, item)
        self.tableWidget.resizeColumnToContents(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot! Been struggling for days with this. Any good resources you recommend I can check out to learn more about pyqt?I find most books only touch the basics and though the Qt docs go way in depth I have a hard time understanding and translating the C++ code for use in python.

Comment: @West The [zetcode PyQt5 tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/) will give you a quite good basic overview. There are [several books listed here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Books) (but I don't have any recommendations). Personally, I think once you have the basics down, the Qt docs are all you need. Most of the C++ examples have been ported to PyQt5, and can be [found here](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples) or in the [latest source code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5). For any remaining gaps, ask a question on SO.